# Default page at end of url

Tags: asp.net, url

my test site suddenly went weird after I added condition for letting %20 at end of urls pass thru, example:

```
localhost/MySite/1234%20
```

redirects to

```
localhost/MySite/1234
```

it was okay, when I was testing it in my local pc, but upon deployment for testing, it redirects to this link

```
localhost/MySite/1234/default.html
```

what do you think may cause this problem? also, "default.html" is my default page when accessing localhost/MySite

it goes to localhost/MySite/default.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using iis? it seems your webserver configuration in your local machine different from your deploying server. Maybe your testing server uses "default page" rule to default.html, something like this

```
<system.webServer>
 <defaultDocument>
  <files>
  <clear />
  <add value="Pages/default.html" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

on your web.config.
try here http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument

Comment: yes I'm using IIS and it says `<add value="default.html" />` on my <defaultDocument>

Comment: is localhost/MySite/1234 a directory? is it supposed to show directory listing? because if you disable defaultDocument, it will show a directory listing. unless you also ddisabled "directory browsing", it will show HTTP "404 File Does Not Exist" page.
summary, just disable it by removing that line. and leave only <clear/> tag.

Comment: nope, it is not a directory.. it's a query string written in short hand url

Comment: does removing the `<add value="default.html" />` after `<clear/>` tag works?